# VBA for MS Access 2007 Google Earth Project

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have found several examples where folks have written code for mapping points on google earth via a button on an access form which loops throug data in a table or query.  I have used this code to map multiple points by looping through the recordset.  I am now trying to connect the points with a polygon.  I have included the code for the polygon within the same loop code.  However, instead of one polygon connecting the points, a polygon is made for each point.  I need to include all of the points that were found during the loop into the polygon code for it to work correctly.  Not sure how to do this though.  Code below.  This is looking at a table with the fields SiteID, LongW, LatN.  Each site has 4-8 points.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
        f.Write "<Placemark>"
            f.Write "<name>" & rst!SiteID & "</name>"
            f.Write "<styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hll</styleUrl>"
            f.Write "<Point>"
            f.Write "<coordinates>" & rst!LongW & "," & rst!LatN & "</coordinates>"
            f.Write "</Point>"
        f.Write "</Placemark>"

        f.Write "<Placemark>"
            f.Write "<name>UntitledPolygon</name>"
            f.Write "<styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>"
            f.Write "<Polygon>"
            f.Write "<tessellate>1</tessellate>"
            f.Write "<outerBoundaryIs>"
            f.Write "<LinearRing>"
            f.Write "<coordinates>" & rst!LongW & "," & rst!LatN & "</coordinates>"
            f.Write strText
        f.Write "</LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>" & vbCrLf
rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I don't know if your coordinates need to be in a certain order. Or if they need to include an altitude.

The basic idea here is that you shouldn't output the polygon text/code until you've gathered all relevant coordinates. Which means you do it after your loop.

```vb
Dim sCoord as String
Do While Not rst.EOF
    f.Write "<Placemark>"
        f.Write "<name>" & rst!SiteID & "</name>"
        f.Write "<styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hll</styleUrl>"
        f.Write "<Point>"
        f.Write "<coordinates>" & rst!LongW & "," & rst!LatN & "</coordinates>"
        sCoord = sCoord & rst!LongW & "," & rst!LatN & vbCrLf
        f.Write "</Point>"
    f.Write "</Placemark>"
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

f.Write "<Placemark>"
    f.Write "<name>UntitledPolygon</name>"
    f.Write "<styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>"
    f.Write "<Polygon>"
    f.Write "<tessellate>1</tessellate>"
    f.Write "<outerBoundaryIs>"
    f.Write "<LinearRing>"
    f.Write "<coordinates>" & sCoord & "</coordinates>"
    f.Write strText
f.Write "</LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>" & vbCrLf
```

Comment: The code you suggested worked.  Thank you for your time and effort.  I knew what I wanted to do but not how to do it.  You provided a straightforward solution.